# Var in R calls function that returns a date, class says "character"

Tags: r, date, subset, readline

Using RStudio 1.1.4, working to run from source but right now testing interactively. Trying to take readline input and subset my data frame by date. So here's the data structure of the frame:

```
'data.frame':   101242 obs. of  10 variables:
$ name      : chr (names)
$ Task_Date : Date, format: "1997-05-09" "1997-05-20" "1997-05-23" "1997-05-28" ...
$ Wo_Num    : chr  "-0-0                             " "-0-0                             " "-0-0                             " "-0-0                             " ...
$ Time_Code : chr  "SH" "SH" "SH" "SH" ...
$ Task_Code : chr  "IND-SH" "IND-SH" "IND-SH" "IND-SH" ...
$ Task      : chr  "SHOP/BREAK TIME" "SHOP/BREAK TIME" "SHOP/BREAK TIME" "SHOP/BREAK TIME" ...
$ hours     : num  2 2 1 1 2 2 2 4 5 8 ...
$ labor_rate: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
$ cost      : num  148 148 74 74 148 148 148 296 370 592 ...
$ Shop      : chr  "Radio" "Radio" "Radio" "Radio" ...
```

Here are the functions:

```
begdate <- function()
{
  n <-  readline(prompt = "Enter begin date:" )
  return(as.Date(n))
}

enddate <- function()
{
  n <-  readline(prompt = "Enter end date:" )
  return(as.Date(n))
}
bdate <- begdate()
edate <- enddate()
```

And here's the interactive output:

> bdate <- begdate()

Enter begin date:12/31/2017

> class(bdate)

[1] "character"

(The same thing is true running it for edate)

And sure enough,

TLSub <- subset(TechLabor, Task_Date >= bdate)

**Error in charToDate(x) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format**

What am I missing here? 
Thanks for the help

Comment: `as.Date.date` requires the input be a `date` object. use `as.Date()`

Comment: The RStudio version is irrelevant - give the R version.

Comment: When I run the sample code, it dies because of the error noted by Alex, with this message:  `Error in as.Date.date(n) : 'n' is not a "date" object`.  I think we aren't seeing the real code.

Comment: I get Mark's error message if I use `as.Date` instead of `as.Date.date`.  The reason is that R won't ever guess M/D/Y format.  If you really want to use that, you need to give it in the `as.Date` call, or use a more forgiving conversion function (like `anytime::anydate("12/31/2017")`, which gets it right).

Comment: sorry, yes I was running it with as.Date but had changed it due to an accidental erasure and misremembering what I had used. But otherwise it's the right code.

Comment: fixed the question

Answer (score 2):

The issue is not about subsetting but about converting date strings.

**First**, we need to distinguish between the internal (numeric) representation of a date in R and the format of a date when it is printed as character string.

**Second**, we have to recognize that around the world, people are used to write dates in different formats. 
E.g., the last day of the year 2017 can be written as

- `12/31/2017`
- `12/31/17`
- `31/12/2017`
- `31.12.2017`
- `31.12.17`
- `20171231`
- `2017/12/31`
- `2017-12-31`

(if we only consider numerical formats). The formats differ in the order in which days, months, and years appear in the string and in the character used to separate the entries.

Unfortunately, some formats are ambiguous, i.e., you cannot decide which format has been used and how to interprete the date string. E.g., what date is represented by the character string `03/04/2017`? The 3rd of April 2017 or the 4th of March 2017? (Things get worse if the year is only given by two digits, e.g., `03/04/05`.)

This is why `as.Date()` has a `format` parameter which can be used to tell R how to interprete the given date string.

However, some formats are called unambiguous because R knows how to interprete the date string without additional hint. First of all, this is the date format `YYYY-MM-DD` as defined in the [ISO 8601 standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). This format is used by default when printing dates, e.g.,

```
Sys.Date()
```

> ```
> [1] "2018-07-04"
> ```

On input, `as.Date()` accepts also `YYYY/MM/DD`, e.g.,

```
as.Date("2017/12/31")
```

> ```
> [1] "2017-12-31"
> ```

So, your two functions can be modified to accept date strings in your preferred format by specifing the `format` parameter:

```
begdate <- function()
{
  n <-  readline(prompt = "Enter begin date:" )
  return(as.Date(n, format = "%m/%d/%Y"))
}

bdate <- begdate(); bdate
```

which now works as expected for your preferred format

> ```
> Enter begin date:12/31/2017
> [1] "2017-12-31"
> ```

but will return `NA` in case of date strings which do not match the specified format

```
bdate <- begdate(); bdate
```

> ```
> Enter begin date:2017-12-31
> [1] NA
> ```

---

With R version 3.5.0 (released 2018-04-23 on CRAN), `as.Date()` has gained a new parameter 
`tryFormats` which takes a character vector of `format` strings to try if `format` is not specified.

```
begdate <- function()
{
  n <-  readline(prompt = "Enter begin date:" )
  return(as.Date(n, tryFormats = c("%Y-%m-%d", "%Y/%m/%d", "%m/%d/%Y")))
}
```

will now accept and interpret three different formats correctly:

> ```
> Enter begin date:2017-12-31
> [1] "2017-12-31"
> Enter begin date:12/31/2017
> [1] "2017-12-31"
> Enter begin date:2017/12/31
> [1] "2017-12-31"
> ```

Comment: How did you discover the argument `tryFormats`? It is not mentioned in the help system neither for `as.Date` nor for `strptime` (which is used "under the hood")...

Comment: @RYoda, `help("as.Date")` mentions `tryFormats` in the *Arguments* section, at least for  my currently installed  R version is 3.5.1.

Comment: Yep, now I can find it too! It must have been introduced after R 3.4.4 (my current version) which says `as.Date(x, format, ...)`, while the help for R 3.5.1 says `as.Date(x, format, tryFormats = c("%Y-%m-%d", "%Y/%m/%d"), optional = FALSE, …)`.

Comment: @RYoda, you are right, I have double checked the release notes: `tryFormats` was introduced with R version 3.5.0. I have updated my answer accordingly. Thank you for pointing out!